# Join objects deletes surfaces, and messes it up

Tags: modeling

When I join 3 objects together they mash up in a wierd way. Instead of joining together, they all go to the same z-coordinate.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are joining bezier curve, and the last you select before your <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>J</kbd> is in 2D (check it out in the *Properties* panel > *Data* > *Shape* > *2D* or *3D*). So either switch it to *3D* or don't select this 2D object at last before your <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>J</kbd>.